# How to use sockets in Lua to telnet?

Tags: sockets, lua, telnet

In Lua, I downloaded the LuaSocket library and then am trying to:

1. Connect using telnet
2. Send some commands
3. receive output from the commands to parse later
4. close telnet

What am I doing wrong with this code that is not making that work?

```
local socket = require("socket")
conn = socket.tcp() 
conn:connect("IP Address",23)
conn:send("password") 
conn:send("enable") 
conn:send("password2") ;; above was all login procedure
conn:send("sh run interfaces ethernet 16")
var1 = conn:receive('*l')
print (var1)
```

I expected this to give me the first line of code printed off by the sh run interfaces ethernet 16 command, but all I get is 2:) 2v sqrt:) sqrt<3... That is, four random symbols that I don't know what they mean.

Any help on what I did wrong here would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

here are those four symbols: [image]

Comment: `telnet` is not a plain-text protocol. What line do you get *after* that line? What do you get if you `conn:receive("*a")` at that point?

Comment: It usually just freezes when I type conn:receive("*a") although I haven't let it go for a long time and there is a LOT of words in that sh run. I will try it again and let it have time and let you know. How do I convert the symbols to plain-text then?

Comment: `"*a"` might hang, so just try reading a second line and seeing if you get any data there too. You don't convert it. It isn't encoded. It just isn't only text. There is non-text control stuff in the telnet protocol.

Comment: It finally went through, it showed me those four symbols then on the next line said passwordenablepassword2 and then Password: which was the receive asking for Password. I believe that I need to do a \n at the end of those quotes to get my information to be put in separately so that the password works correctly, right? Thanks what you've shown me has helped a lot.

Comment: I added in the \n's and it says the four pictures and then on the next line has...

password^Jenable^Jpassword2^Jsh run interfaces ethernet 16^JPassword:

Then the next line says Password: 

Then the next line says the name of the thing I'm telnetting to. Any ideas?

Comment: You are getting echo of your inputs and the outputs from the server. Doing what you want directly like this is going to be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Update: For all who were curious I needed \r to make the commands go on separate lines, and I had to put a sleep time in between each of the commands so the system would have time to load in between them. It then worked perfectly.